# Using Hive's concatenate on a previously concatenated table

Tags: hive, concatenation, orc

I have a hive table reading from orc files which has been previously concatenated using:

```
alter table table_name concatenate
```

As new orc files are being generated, I want to join them too with the previous concatenated file.
I have tried using concatenate again but it will not join the newly created orc files.
Is there a way to do this?